# Mac console app does not connect by WLAN to devices

Tags: macos, logs, console

I want to lookup device logs using the console app (V1.1, 6.0.7). This works when a device is connected by cable.
Devices connected by WLAN are however flagged as not connected, and their logs cannot be shown.
It is neither possible to make log archives using `sudo log collect --device-name "name"` for devices only connected by WLAN, since this gives an error `log: failed to create archive: Device not configured (6)`.
This problem is particularly annoying for a watch that cannot be connected by cable.
Any suggestions how I could see the logs?

Comment: Are you sure this is a WLAN issue? The error seems to indicate that either logging isn't enabled on the watch or you don't have the rights to access it.

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is: Currently only devices connected by cable are accessible, although all devices are logged in with the same Apple ID and are connected to the same WLAN.

Comment: Do you have a device where it works via Ethernet but doesn’t work via WLAN?

Comment: I have 2 iPhones that can be connected by Thunderbolt, and are seen then by the console app. They are not seen when only connected by WLAN.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question: Could you say why? Otherwise it is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: There were 2 of them:

- For some reason, the watch was not connected to the WLAN, although indicated. After a re-boot the console app could connect to the watch. However, no logs were shown.
- I found the solution in [this contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54531698/1987726): One has to install a sysdiagnose profile on the iPhone that can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?name=sysdiagnose) together with installation info. After a re-boot of the watch, the console shows the logs.